# Dynamic update in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic

I have a page in asp.net that I need to change the contents of it based on a database.  Basically, ever couple of seconds, I want to update a label.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer.aspx) control:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<script type="text/C#" runat="server">
    protected void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This method will be called on every 5 seconds
        // Read the database value and update the label
        LblStatus.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="scm" runat="server" />
        <asp:Label ID="LblStatus" runat="server" />
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer" runat="server" Interval="5000" OnTick="Timer_Tick" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: (I have to wait a couple minutes before it will let me click the checkmark)  ANSWERED!  Thanks!  :)